# Creating a gmail group using an alias domain (Google)

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-groups

I have the Google apps account: domain1.com

I have the following accounts set up:

Jane (jane@firstdomain.com)

Ben (ben@firstdomain.com)

Joe (joe@firstdomain.com)

I have the domain seconddomain.com set up as an alias of firstdomain.com. So Jane, Ben and Joe have jane@seconddomain.com, ben@seconddomain.com and joe@dseconddomain.com.

I want to create a group using the alias email, such that group@seconddomain.com includes Jane, Ben, and Bill as recipients of that email address. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. But a few notes to consider when doing so.

1. It is only possible for you to create a group using @seconddomain.com if the group was added as a Secondary Domain, not a User alias domain. You can read more about it [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7502379).
2. You would need to manually create the group, and a dropdown option should appear letting you choose which Domain you would like to use as the domain for your group email. You can read more about creating groups [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9400082).

Comment: Hey Diego, in my case I have configured my second domain as an alias, is it still possible to create a group based on that second domain?

Comment: @Carlos No, you cannot create a group entity on the Admin Console if the domain is added as a User Alias Domain. 

" It is only possible for you to create a group using group@seconddomain.com if the group was added as a Secondary Domain, not a User alias domain. You can read more about it [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7502379). ". Although just for clarity, if you choose the User Alias Domain option when adding your alias domain, all existing group entity will have a "Group Alias".